# Change Bootstrap badge-danger upon disconnection

Tags: javascript, html

New to programming and i am fiddeling with something i cant get working.

The issue is:
I vant to change bootstrap badge-danger to badge-success depending on the connection status.

The script i am using is:

```
<script>
    function updateIndicator() {
        document.getElementById('indicator').textContent = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
    }
</script>
```

With:

```
<body onload="updateIndicator()" ononline="updateIndicator()" onoffline="updateIndicator()">
<p>The network is: <span id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>
```

I have a feeling that the solution is fairly simple. :P
I have tried to place:

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">Disconnected</span>
```

On difrent places in the code but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function updateIndicator() {
  let indicator = document.getElementById('indicator')
  indicator.className = navigator.onLine ? 'badge badge-pill badge-success' : 'badge badge-pill badge-danger';
  indicator.textContent = navigator.onLine ? 'online' : 'offline';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<body onload="updateIndicator()" ononline="updateIndicator()" onoffline="updateIndicator()">
  <p>The network is: <span id="indicator">(state unknown)</span>
```

You can also listen online with windows event

```
window.addEventListener('online',updateIndicator);
window.addEventListener('offline',updateIndicator);
```